# PHP CURL image upload to remote System

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following code

```
$ch = curl_init("http://198.155.239.118/~bulacs/ssapi-staging/images/upload_images");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt(
$ch,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
array(
     'image' =>
        '@' . $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']
        . ';filename=' . $_FILES['image']['name']
        . ';type='     . $_FILES['image']['type']
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
```

Here there is no error and showing success message but actually the file is not moving to destination.

Comment: Maybe permission issues?

Comment: best option save it locally and send saved image url using curl and get image from url using curl on another server

Comment: use domain name instead of ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'image' => '@' . $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ));
```

I did this and I only set the tmp_name, like above. So it should work.

Comment: Getting "Moved Permanently" success message but nothing is happening

Comment: "Moved Permanently" means you use wrong destination URL, which does not receive your file but redirects you to another URL, so the file is not uploaded.